# evolution plugin for exchange missing in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, evolution, ms-exchange

Just upgraded from 12.04 which evolution contained a plugin for MS Exchange.  Can anyone tell me where I can download that plugin for 14.04? Unfortunately, the mail servers I use do not support imap or pop, so exchange is my only option.

Answer (score 14):

run in termina:

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
```

After that you can select new, *Exchange Web Services* server type in new account dialog.

Comment: I get `E: Package 'evolution-ews' has no installation candidate
`. Is this still available? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Comment: I found a link to a binary package for 14.04 here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/evolution-ews/3.10.2-0ubuntu2